# MATLAB - image huffman encoding

Tags: image, matlab, huffman-code

I have a homework in which i have to convert some images to grayscale and compress them using huffman encoding. I converted them to grayscale and then i tried to compress them but i get an error. I used the code i found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8631044/matlab-image-compression).

Here is the code i'm using:

```
A=imread('Gray\36.png');
[symbols,p]=hist(A,unique(A))
p=p/sum(p)
[dict,avglen]=huffmandict(symbols,p)
comp=huffmanenco(A,dict)
```

This is the error i get. It occurs at the second line.

```
Error using eps
Class must be 'single' or 'double'.

Error in hist (line 90)
    bins = xx + eps(xx);
```

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks.

P.S. how can i find the compression ratio for each image?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that when you specify the bin locations (the second input argument of 'hist'), they need to be single or double.  The vector A itself does not, though.  That's nice because sometimes you don't want to convert your whole dataset from an integer type to floating precision.  This will fix your code:

```
[symbols,p]=hist(A,double(unique(A)))
```

[Click here](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-2RFPNI/?product=ML&solution=1-2RFPNI) to see this issue is discussed more in detail.

Answer (score 0):

first, try :

```
whos A
```

Seems like its type must be single or double. If not, just do `A = double(A)` after the imread line. Should work that way, however I'm surprised hist is not doing the conversion...
[EDIT] I have just tested it, and I am right, hist won't work in uint8, but it's okay as soon as I convert my image to double.

Comment: i did that. Here is the code `A=imread('Gray\36.png');
A = double(A);
[symbols,p]=hist(A,unique(A))
p=p/sum(p)
[dict,avglen]=huffmandict(symbols,p)
comp=huffmanenco(A,dict)` and now i get the error, `Error using huffmandict (line 71)
The symbol input must be a vector`

Comment: symbols is not a vector. Actually, hist gives you n the frequency counts in each row, and xout the bin location (i.e. the number of gray levels). They are bidimensional. So as I understand it, just sum up the values in symbols respectively to its columns, that will give you the vector you want. GUESS : symbols=symbols/sum(symbols) ;)

Comment: i did it this way and it works but it is really slow `I=imread('Gray\36.png');
[m,n]=size(I);
Totalcount=m*n;
cnt=1;
sigma=0;
%computing the cumulative probability.
for i=0:255
k=I==i;
count(cnt)=sum(k(:));
%pro array is having the probabilities
pro(cnt)=count(cnt)/Totalcount;
sigma=sigma+pro(cnt);
cumpro(cnt)=sigma;
cnt=cnt+1;
end;
symbols = [0:255];
%Huffman code Dictionary
dict = huffmandict(symbols,pro);
%function which converts array to vector
vec_size = 1;
for p = 1:m
for q = 1:n
newvec(vec_size) = I(p,q);
vec_size = vec_size+1;
end
end
%Huffman Encodig
hcode = huffmanenco(newvec,dict);`

Comment: did you try what I wrote ? Honestly I am wondering if this is not just a confusion between p and symbols. Will try it on my own.

Comment: i just tried it. i get an error. It says that Source symbols repeat in  huffmandict. :(

Comment: Yes I just got that too... sorry sijoune I can't help you any further, I don't really have time right now and can't focus on your problem as much as I would like so I rather give in. Good luck! (I was right about double at least remember that ;) )